# Can I decompose the Lagrange interpolating polynomial of the sum of 2 functions into 2 separate Lagrange polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

For example:`L[x0,x1,...,xn;f+g]=?=L[x0,x1,...,xn;f] + L[x0,x1,...,xn;g]` where f and g are ordinary functions, not neccessarily polynomials......

Answer (score 3):

If $L[x_0, \ldots, x_n; f]$ means a polynomial of degree $ \le n$ that has the same values as $f$ at $x_0, \ldots, x_n$, then yes, this is true.

Comment: so in my case f:=x^n+x^(n-1)+...+1 and g:= -1/(x+1) and I want to calculate L[x0,x1,...,xn; f+g] but I don't know how I should do it.....

Comment: $f$ is already a polynomial of degree $n$, so its interpolating polynomial is itself.

Comment: yes, I agree, but what about g?